# arbitrary intersection of fields is itself an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> Show that an arbitrary intersection of fields is itself, a field.

At first, I thought that it's enough to prove thie same for subfields as any field is a subfield. However, not every sub field is a field so it's a no-go.

The usual way seems to be the only other option. However, how am I supposed to show the properties for infinite case? Is the following method okay?

Let $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{n}}$ be an arbitrary collection of fields of the same sample space $\Omega$.

1. To show that $\Omega$ belongs to the intersection is it okay to say that it follows from the fact that $\Omega\in A_i$ for all $i \in\mathbb{N}$?

Other properties- closed under complementation and finite union would also follow similarly if the previous logic is correct. Is it? Or is there a better way to prove it.

Comment: Arbitrary collections are not indexed by $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @geetha290krm aha right. how do I do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

For $i\in I$ (where $I$ denotes an *arbitrary* index set) let $\mathcal F_i$ be a field on set $\Omega$ and let:$$\mathcal F:=\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal F_i$$
Then indeed $\Omega\in\mathcal F_i$ for every $i\in I$ implies that $\Omega\in\mathcal F$. Actually the two statements are even equivalent.

Based on this principle it can also be shown that $\mathcal F$ has the other characteristics of a field.

This is simple on its own and there is no better way to prove it.